# Sumar minutos en una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo una tabla "Programacion" con los siguientes datos(NO MODIFICABLE):

```
HoraInicio = 08:15 (Char 5),
HoraFin = 12:15 (Char 5),
TiempoPromedioAtencion = 15 (INT),
IdProgramacion = 79647 (INT)
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacer una consulta en la cual sume el campo `HoraInicio "08:15" + TiempoPromedioAtencion "15" como un bucle que finalice en HoraFin "12:15"`
y obtener el resultado en una sola columna, separada por filas obviamente, como el siguiente:

```
HorasDisponible   
08:15 - 08:30  
08:30 - 08:45  
08:45 - 09:00  
...  

12:00 - 12:15
```

o en columnas separadas como:

```
HorasDisponible1 = 08:15,
HorasDisponible2 = 08:30
...
HorasDisponible1 = 12:00,
HorasDisponible2 = 12:15
```

Por el momento he logrado sumar correctamente `HoraInicio "08:15" + TiempoPromedioAtencion "15"` con este código de consulta SQL:

```
Select DATEADD(s,TiempoPromedioAtencion*60,0)+CONVERT(datetime, HoraInicio,120) 
as HorasDisponbile  from ProgramacionMedica
where  IdProgramacion= '79647'
```

Arrojándome el siguiente resultado en una sola columna:

```
HorasDisponible   
1900-01-01 08:30:00.000
```

**¿Se podrá mejorar esta consulta para poder arrojar los resultados que deseo?** O usar otro tipo de consulta que me pueden brindar. Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estas utilizando?

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]. Es muy importante que digas que base de datos estas usando. sql es solo un lenguaje aplicable a muchas bases de datos, y no va a ser la misma solucion (si existe) para cada base

Comment: Utilizo SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo mediante una tabla de números hecha al vuelo. Si no sabes lo que es una tabla de números o como se utiliza te recomiendo investigarlo. En inglés son conocidas como Tally Tables y hay artículos excelentes de [Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) y [Dwain Camps](http://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/). Creo que alguien se puso a traducir [el artículo de Jeff](https://geeks.ms/lmblanco/2014/09/01/creacin-de-tablas-numricas-auxiliares-tally-tables-1/).

Es importante hacer notar que no se deben de guardar estos datos como cadenas sino como un tipo time o datetime que marque el inicio del periodo. El cálculo se puede hacer de forma muy sencilla para su presentación final.

```
DECLARE @HoraInicio CHAR(5) = '08:15',
        @HoraFin CHAR(5) = '12:15',
        @TiempoPromedioAtencion INT = 15;

WITH 
E(n) AS(  -- 10 líneas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 líneas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 líneas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
), 
cteTally(n) AS( --Usamos TOP para usar solo las líneas necesarias.
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF( MINUTE, CAST(@HoraInicio AS time), CAST(@HoraFin AS time))/@TiempoPromedioAtencion)
        --Creamos una serie de números que inicia en 0 y multiplicamos por el tiempo promedio de atención para obtener los rangos
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) * @TiempoPromedioAtencion n
    FROM E4
) --Convertimos los parámetros en tipo time y les agregamos el rango (zero para el primero)
--Después los regresamos a un tipo texto usando LEFT (esto ahorra código)
SELECT LEFT( DATEADD(MI, n, CAST( @HoraInicio AS time)), 5) 
        + ' - ' 
        --Hacemos lo mismo con el final pero agregando el tiempo de atención
        + LEFT( DATEADD(MI, n + @TiempoPromedioAtencion, CAST( @HoraInicio AS time)), 5)
FROM cteTally;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución está basada en:

- La generación de números consecutivos, para lo cual utilizo una serie de *Common Table Expressions (CTE)*, que va construyendo la solución *al vuelo*. Para obtener números consecutivos del 1 al 10,000 lo haría de esta forma:

  ```
    with
      RE (N) as (select 1 union all select N from RE)
    , E1 as (select top 10 * from RE) --10
    , E2 as (select a.N from E1 a, E1 b) --100
    , E4 as (select a.N from E2 a, E2 b) --10000
    , Generador as (select top 10000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) N from E4)
    select *
      from Generador
  ```
- Un primer *CTE*, llamado `Programacion` construye también *al vuelo* tu tabla de base con un par de registros, el que mencionas en tu pregunta y otro cualquiera.
- Un *CTE* posterior, llamado `ProgramacionH` (de programación en horas) extrae los datos de `Programacion`, haciendo las siguientes conversiones de tipo de dato, nombres de columna y cálculos:

  - `HoraInicio` y `HoraFin` se convierten al tipo de dato `Time` y se llamarán `HoraInicioProgramacion` y `HoraFinProgramacion` respectivamente
  - Se hace el cálculo de los `MinutosDisponibles` haciendo la diferencia de estas dos horas.
  - Se calcula la cantidad de `IntervalosDisponibles` haciendo la división de los `MinutosDisponibles` entre el `TiempoPromedioAtencion`.
- Finalmente hago un [`inner join`][1] entre `ProgramacionH` y el `Generador` de números, para obtener como resultado tantas filas como `IntervalosDisponibles` hay en el rango de horas de cada registro de `ProgramacionH`. Para cada fila, con aritmética de fechas, calculo la hora de inicio y la hora de fin del intervalo.

Puesto todo en código, sería:

```sql
with 
Programacion as (
select *
  from (values (79647, '08:15', '12:15', 15)
             , (79648, '08:00', '11:00', 10)
         
       ) q1 (idProgramacion, HoraInicio, HoraFin, TiempoPromedioAtencion)
)
, RE (N) as (select 1 union all select N from RE)
, E1 as (select top 10 * from RE) --10
, E2 as (select a.N from E1 a, E1 b) --100
, E4 as (select a.N from E2 a, E2 b) --10000
, Generador as (select top 10000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) N from E4)
, ProgramacionH as (
select   p.idProgramacion
       , cast(p.HoraInicio as Time) HoraInicioProgramacion
       , cast(p.HoraFin as Time) HoraFinProgramacion
       , p.TiempoPromedioAtencion
       , datediff(minute, cast(p.HoraInicio as Time), cast(p.HoraFin as Time)) MinutosDisponibles
       , datediff(minute, cast(p.HoraInicio as Time), cast(p.HoraFin as Time)) / p.TiempoPromedioAtencion IntervalosDisponibles
  from Programacion p
)
select   p.idProgramacion
       /*
       , p.HoraInicioProgramacion
       , p.HoraFinProgramacion
       , p.TiempoPromedioAtencion
       , p.MinutosDisponibles
       , p.IntervalosDisponibles
       */
       , g.N NumeroIntervalo
       , DateAdd(minute, (g.N - 1) * p.TiempoPromedioAtencion, p.HoraInicioProgramacion) HoraInicioIntervalo
       , DateAdd(minute, (g.N) * p.TiempoPromedioAtencion, p.HoraInicioProgramacion) HoraFinIntervalo
  from ProgramacionH p
       inner join Generador g on g.N <= p.IntervalosDisponibles
 where p.idProgramacion = 79647
 order by p.idProgramacion, g.N
```

Lo que arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
idProgramacion NumeroIntervalo      HoraInicioIntervalo HoraFinIntervalo
-------------- -------------------- ------------------- ----------------
79647          1                    08:15:00.0000000    08:30:00.0000000
79647          2                    08:30:00.0000000    08:45:00.0000000
79647          3                    08:45:00.0000000    09:00:00.0000000
79647          4                    09:00:00.0000000    09:15:00.0000000
79647          5                    09:15:00.0000000    09:30:00.0000000
79647          6                    09:30:00.0000000    09:45:00.0000000
79647          7                    09:45:00.0000000    10:00:00.0000000
79647          8                    10:00:00.0000000    10:15:00.0000000
79647          9                    10:15:00.0000000    10:30:00.0000000
79647          10                   10:30:00.0000000    10:45:00.0000000
79647          11                   10:45:00.0000000    11:00:00.0000000
79647          12                   11:00:00.0000000    11:15:00.0000000
79647          13                   11:15:00.0000000    11:30:00.0000000
79647          14                   11:30:00.0000000    11:45:00.0000000
79647          15                   11:45:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000
79647          16                   12:00:00.0000000    12:15:00.0000000

(16 rows affected)


Completion time: 2020-07-19T18:47:06.6917077-06:00
```

La ventaja de hacerlo de esta manera es que puedes obtener los intervalos para cualquier cantidad de registros de la tabla subyacente `Programacion` en una sola consulta, si eso fuera de tu interés.

En el ejemplo he agregado un `where` para limitar el resultado al registro de ejemplo de tu pregunta para no llenar de muchos datos la respuesta.

He utilizado un generador de hasta 10000 registros tomando en cuenta que hay hasta 1440 intervalos de un minuto en un día, por lo que he considerado suficiente este. Podría ser mayor o menor de acuerdo a las necesidades reales.

Answer (score 0):

Dada una tabla `Programacion` con varios rangos de horas y promedios, y usando una tabla para los resultados, se puede calcular en un único bucle siempre que primero se averigüe el mayor número de intervalos que va a haber. Pongamos el ejemplo:

```
set nocount on
declare @Programacion table (
      HoraInicio             char(5)
    , HoraFin                char(5)
    , TiempoPromedioAtencion int
    , IdProgramacion         int
)
insert @Programacion values 
    ('08:15', '12:15', 15, 79647), ('08:00', '11:00', 10, 79648)

declare @res table (IdPrg int, Orden int, HIni time(0), HFin time(0))

-- N.º máximo de Intervalos = dif en minutos / promedio
declare @i int =
    (select max(dateDiff(mi, cast(HoraInicio as time),
                             cast(HoraFin    as time)) 
                / TiempoPromedioAtencion)
        from @Programacion)
-- Bucle inverso (mayor a menor rango horario)
while @i > 0
begin
    insert @res
    select idProgramacion
        ,  @i
        ,  dateAdd(mi, (@i-1)*TiempoPromedioAtencion, cast(HoraInicio as time))
        ,  dateAdd(mi, (@i)  *TiempoPromedioAtencion, cast(HoraInicio as time))
    from @Programacion
    where  dateAdd(mi, (@i)  *TiempoPromedioAtencion, cast(HoraInicio as time))
             <= cast(HoraFin as time)
    set @i -= 1
end
select IdPrg as IdProgramacion
    , convert(char(5), HIni, 14) + ' - '
    + convert(char(5), HFin, 14) as HorasDisponible
    , HIni as HoraDisponible1
    , HFin as HoraDisponible2
from @res
order by IdPrg, Orden
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v7W7kZ4I)